# how to add custom validation message in suitecrm api

Tags: suitecrm

I configure json api in my suitecrm and now i want to add validation mandatory fields for some parameter please suggest me how to add validation and custom message.
I tried to add validation but can't get success is any idea how to configure validation message display

Comment: i solved using logic_hooks. in logic_hooks use before_save

Answer (score 0):

Use before_save logic hooks in that module in which you want to add validation then create you own method to check validation e.g. for checking pan number you can use pan regix then apiException

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this one to your custom api controller

here`s my sample **custom/application/Api/V8/Controller/CustomController.php**

```
namespace Api\V8\Controller;

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
class CustomController extends BaseController
{
public function saveLeads(Request 
$request, Response $response, array $args)
{
 try {
        $jsonResponse = $request->getParams();
        $leadBean = \BeanFactory::newBean('Leads');
        if(empty(jsonResponse['name'])
        {
            $resultMessage['Error'] = 'Please filled up the Name';
        }else{
            $leadBean->name = jsonResponse['name'];
            $leadBean->save();
            $resultMessage['Succes'] = Leads Has been created';
        }
        return $this->generateResponse($response, $resultMessage, 201);
    }   catch (\Exception $exception){
        return $this->generateErrorResponse($response, $exception, 400);
    }
}
```